# Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT with segue in swift

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue

I have several tableview. I am trying to make a simple application and after adding more view when I get the third tableView  this error "Thread 1 Signal SIGABRT" and the app wont open in iOS Simulator. The error points to this line of code:

```
let VC :DetailCityTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailCityTableViewController
```

and display error :

```
 Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x102af47f8) to 'balen.DetailCityTableViewController' (0x1013d7560).
(lldb)
```

> Full Code :

tableview2 pass to tableView3

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let path : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    if segue.identifier == "DetailCitySegue" {

        let VC :DetailCityTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailCityTableViewController
        VC.urlDetailCity = urlDetail!// pass url city

        VC.cityIdSelectet =  cityId[path.row] //pas CountryID selected

        print(cityId[path.row])
    }           
}
```

I am , I think the problem is `segue` .What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the problem is '

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewController' (0x102af47f8) to
>   'balen.DetailCityTableViewController''

You didn't change the class type of the view controller to DetailCityTableViewController in interface builder or the segue has a different destination than you think.

Comment: :))) thanks .
I forgot  change the class type of the view controller to DetailCityTableViewController in interface builder.
There's one day I am engaged

Comment: Common mistake. You'll learn soon enough to recognise and interpret these minor errors.