# Segue from an UITableViewController to another one issue

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, segue, sigabrt

I am trying to segue 2 ViewControllers of of UI Table type, but it shows me an error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT", here the code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPlates"{
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{

            let selectedRecipe = self.recetas[indexPath.row]
            let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! PlateViewController


            destinationViewController.recetas = [selectedRecipe]

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't use `as!` what kind of object is `destinationViewController`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT with segue in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667026/thread-1-signal-sigabrt-with-segue-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you haven't set a class (PlateViewController) for desired destination ViewController in your storyboard (I guess in Main.storyboard)

[image: Storyboard settings]

Comment: I can´t believe me :facepalm:, that's right, thanks a lot